# SSMA "Required mdb-file $accessFileName is not loaded"

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016, sql-server-migration-assi

Hello Stackoverflow this is my first time here so please be easy on me.

I am trying to use a SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) to import a .accdb Microsoft access file type to a SQL server. However when I try to import the file I get an error that says

> Required mdb-file $fileName is not loaded

I know .mdb is the file type of access <=2007 however I am using access 2016. I am told that SSMA is the best way to import a .accdb over to a SQL server but can I if it needs to be a .mdb?

If I can import a .accdb using an SSMA what am I doing wrong to get this error and if I can't what program should I be using to do the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by installing Access runtime even with the full version of access on the computer it still needed runtime for external programs to use apparently